# C#, WPF -> GUI should not freeze while Updating in BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, backgroundworker

This is my project so far:

```
private void test()
    {
        var rows = GetDataGridRows(dgVarConfig);

        Dictionary<TextBlock, String> dic = new Dictionary<TextBlock, string>();
        foreach (DataGridRow r in rows)
        {
            TextBlock tb = cMatchEx.GetCellContent(r) as TextBlock;
            dic.Add(tb, tb.Text);
        }

        if (!syntaxWorker.IsBusy)
            syntaxWorker.RunWorkerAsync(dic);
    }



    private void syntaxWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Argument == null)
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        else
        {
            Dictionary<TextBlock, String> dic = (Dictionary<TextBlock, String>)e.Argument;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<TextBlock, String> kvp in dic)
            {

                kvp.Key.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    kvp.Key.Inlines.Clear();
                    Syntax.Highlight(kvp.Value).ForEach(x => kvp.Key.Inlines.Add(x));
                }));
            }

        }
    }
```

Syntax.Highlight:

```
public static class Syntax
{
    static Regex subFormula = new Regex(@"\w+\(\)");
    static Regex sapFormula = new Regex(@"\w+\(([^)]+)\)");
    static Regex strings = new Regex(@"\'[^']+\'");
    static Regex numerals = new Regex(@"\b[0-9\.]+\b");
    static Regex characteristic = new Regex(@"(?:)?\w+(?:)?");
    static Regex andOr = new Regex(@"( and )|( AND )|( or )|( OR )");
    static Regex not = new Regex(@"(not )|(NOT )");

    private static Brush[] colorArray;

    public static List<Run> Highlight(String input)
    {


        colorArray = new Brush[input.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            colorArray[i] = Brushes.Black;

        //Reihenfolge beibehalten!!
        assignColor(Brushes.Blue, characteristic.Matches(input));
        assignColor(Brushes.Black, andOr.Matches(input));
        assignColor(Brushes.Black, numerals.Matches(input));
        assignColor(Brushes.Orange, strings.Matches(input));
        assignColor(Brushes.DeepPink, subFormula.Matches(input));
        assignColor(Brushes.Green, sapFormula.Matches(input));
        assignColor(Brushes.Green, not.Matches(input));


        int index = 0;

        List<Run> runList = new List<Run>();

        foreach (Char character in input)
        {

            runList.Add(new Run(character.ToString()) { Foreground = colorArray[index] });
            index++;
        }


        colorArray = null;
        return runList;
    }

    public static void Check(TextBlock textBlock)
    {

    }


    private static void assignColor(Brush brush, MatchCollection matchCollection)
    {
        foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
        {
            int start = match.Index;
            int end = start + match.Length;

            for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
            {
                colorArray[i] = brush;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this code, the gui freezes for about 2 seconds. Is there any way to build up the gui step by step and avoid any freezing?
Its no problem to see how its building up, just the freezing is a problem.

Hope anybody knows how to resolve this.

Comment: The reason for the freezing is that the backgroundworker is basically useless the way it's currently implemented ; only the loop logic is performed in the background, since the brunt of the work is inside the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`. try finding a way to make `Highlight(string input)` faster, or moving its logic to a background worker or thread of its own. (you could raise an event once that is finished to update the visuals of the control, or invoke the ui thread at the end)

Comment: and how do i achieve that? i cant build a run and update a textblock with it

Comment: you can definitely *build* the runs in a background thread.

Comment: if i do that, i get the following error: `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`

Answer (score 1):

You could move a good portion of the work outside of the invoke like this :

One small caveat : i'm not entirely sure how you retreive the text of the textboxes. you might have to do a separate invoke for that (see comment in the code)

```
public class RunInfo
{
    public string Content { get; set;}
    public Color foreground { get; set; }
    public RunInfo(string content)
    {
        Content = content;
    }

    public Run AsRun()
    {
       return new Run(Content){ Foreground = foreground };
    }

}



public static class Syntax
{
    static Regex subFormula = new Regex(@"\w+\(\)");
    static Regex sapFormula = new Regex(@"\w+\(([^)]+)\)");
    static Regex strings = new Regex(@"\'[^']+\'");
    static Regex numerals = new Regex(@"\b[0-9\.]+\b");
    static Regex characteristic = new Regex(@"(?:)?\w+(?:)?");
    static Regex andOr = new Regex(@"( and )|( AND )|( or )|( OR )");
    static Regex not = new Regex(@"(not )|(NOT )");

    private static Brush[] colorArray;

    public static List<RunInfo> Highlight(String input)
    {


        colorArray = new Brush[input.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            colorArray[i] = Brushes.Black;

        //Reihenfolge beibehalten!!
        assignColor(Brushes.Blue, characteristic.Matches(input));
        assignColor(Brushes.Black, andOr.Matches(input));
        assignColor(Brushes.Black, numerals.Matches(input));
        assignColor(Brushes.Orange, strings.Matches(input));
        assignColor(Brushes.DeepPink, subFormula.Matches(input));
        assignColor(Brushes.Green, sapFormula.Matches(input));
        assignColor(Brushes.Green, not.Matches(input));


        int index = 0;

        List<Run> runList = new List<Run>();

        foreach (Char character in input)
        {

            runList.Add(new RunInfo(character.ToString()) { Foreground = colorArray[index] });
            index++;
        }


        colorArray = null;
        return runList;
    }

    public static void Check(TextBlock textBlock)
    {

    }


    private static void assignColor(Brush brush, MatchCollection matchCollection)
    {
        foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
        {
            int start = match.Index;
            int end = start + match.Length;

            for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
            {
                colorArray[i] = brush;
            }
        }
    }
}




private void syntaxWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Argument == null)
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    else
    {
        Dictionary<TextBlock, String> dic = (Dictionary<TextBlock, String>)e.Argument;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<TextBlock, String> kvp in dic)
        {
            //i am unsure if this line will work. if it does not, you might need to do a separate dispatcher invoke in order to retreive the text from the textbox.
            List<RunInfo> runinfoObjects = Syntax.Highlight(kvp.Value); 
            kvp.Key.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
            {
                kvp.Key.Inlines.Clear();
                //we'd run into problems here, since wpf won't allow us to add elements created in a background thread. since we now make the Run object inside the invoke, we should be fine.
                runinfoObjects.ForEach(x => kvp.Key.Inlines.Add(x.AsRun()));
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated the answer. you can't add a WPF element to the UI thread when it was constructed in another thread.